# How to add dropdown page selection in LengthAwarePaginator using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am using script for Laravel pagination. I want to add per page dropdown selection in LengthAwarePaginator so that i can list of all entries according to page selection in my script.
My script:

```
   public function index(Request $request){

    $data = [];
    $keyword = request('keyword','');
    $applicationData = $this->ppObjAdmin->getBackOfficeApplications(['keyword' =>$keyword]);
    $paginate =10;
    $pageStart = request('page', 1);
    $offSet    = ($pageStart * $paginate) - $paginate;
    $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($applicationData,$offSet, $paginate);
    $journeyListData = new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage , count($applicationData) , $paginate , Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() , ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);
    $data['journeyData'] = $journeyListData;
    $data['searchKeyword'] = $keyword;

    return view('admin.listing',$data);
}
```

Dropdown html:

```
                                <select class="page_limit pgination-select" onchange="page_limit(this)">
                                    <option value="10" >10 Entries per page</option>
                                    <option value="20 " >20 Entries per page</option>
                                    <option value="30 " >30 Entries per page</option>
                                    <option value="50">50 Entries per page</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>`enter code here`
```

Please see attached link problem show more clear .   http://prntscr.com/guto00

Please  help in this script for dropdown selection.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put your select into a form, like this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <select class="page_limit pgination-select" name="limit">
        <option value="10">10 Entries per page</option>
        <option value="20">20 Entries per page</option>
        <option value="30">30 Entries per page</option>
        <option value="50">50 Entries per page</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Then you just check in your controller for the parameter in the request:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $data = [];
    $keyword = request('keyword','');
    $applicationData = $this->ppObjAdmin->getBackOfficeApplications(['keyword' =>$keyword]);
    $page_limit = $request->limit ?: 10;
    $currentPage = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1;

    // applicationData has to be an instance of the class Collection
    $items = $applicationData instanceof Collection ? $applicationData : Collection::make($applicationData);
    $itemsForCurrentPage = $items->forPage($currentPage, $page_limit);

    $journeyListData = new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, $items->count(), $page_limit , $currentPage, ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);

    $data['journeyData'] = $journeyListData;
    $data['searchKeyword'] = $keyword;

    return view('admin.listing',$data);
}
```

Comment: But pagination on bottom page still exist 
all records is not showing 
http://prntscr.com/gut3r5

Comment: Ok, actually you don't have to slice your array, just make sure it is a Collection, so you can paginate it. See if my edited answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

To me the more elegant form is of this way(http://novate.co.uk/allow-user-to-choose-pagination-length-via-dropdown-laravel/):

When displaying the links, we need to append the current page length

> {{ $members->appends(compact('items'))->links() }}

The Select list is created as follows

```
> <form>
>     <select id="pagination">
>         <option value="5" @if($items == 5) selected @endif >5</option>
>         <option value="10" @if($items == 10) selected @endif >10</option>
>         <option value="25" @if($items == 25) selected @endif >25</option>
>     </select> </form>
> 
> <script>
>     document.getElementById('pagination').onchange = function() { 
>         window.location = "{!! $members->url(1) !!}&items=" + this.value; 
>     };  </script>
```

Changing the dropdown causes the page to be reloaded, passing `items=10` etc to the controller. The controller checks for items or uses a default value.

> ```
> public function index(Request $request)
> {
>     $items = $request->items ?? 10;      // get the pagination number or a default
>
>     $club = Club::findOrFail(session('club'));
>
>     $members = $club->members()->paginate($items);
>
>     return view('club.' . config('app.locale') . '.index')
>         ->withClub($club)
>         ->withMembers($members)
>         ->withItems($items);
> }
> ```

In the controller method, $itemsis passed back to the view so that it can be used to ensure the current length is selected